# How to show Android process status

Tags: android, linux, process, kernel, multicore

I am doing some experiment on the Linux kernel. I am modifying the scheduling work on a multicore system. I want to check which CPU the process is working on. Is there any Android APP or API to get these information?

Comment: on android device ?

Comment: It is also okay if I can check those information from my PC. As long as I can get the information